# users.createScrap - Hyves Api method does not exist

Tags: api, social-networking

I'm has been trying to do method users.createScrap but has been retrieving an error "Hyves Api method does not exist".
You can read about this method here: http://www.hyves-developers.nl/documentation/data-api/methods/2.0/users.createscrap

Please, explain where I'm wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a feature of the Hyves-API that is private, it needs to be enabled by Hyves. If you can send a request to hyves-api@hyves.nl with an explanation, what you are going to use it for. Then they can see if they can enable it for you.

Kind regards,

Derk